# how to calculate surface area of rectangular prism with given volume

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, optimization

I am doing a math project on optimisation and have a rectangular prism with a volume of 100cm3 but no other information. I am supposed to analyse whether the manufacturer of that product has designed the optimal package to hold that volume. Any help?

Comment: You have two unknown but related variables, the length of a side of the square base and the height of the prism. You need the volume $V$ expressed as a function of those two variables and the surface area $S$ also expressed as a function of those two variables. Assuming that the manufacturer wants to minimize the surface area, use the formula for $V$ to express one of the two variables in terms of the other and substitute that into the equation for $S$ and use the method you learned in class for minimizing a functions $S$ defined in terms of a single variable.

Comment: p.s. You should attempt to work this problem for yourself using the outline which I gave in my previous comment.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales How do you know the base is square?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales thank you but it's a cuboid not a square-based prism

Comment: @EthanBolker Ah, thanks for pointing that out. Evidently I misread the problem. The volume and surface area will be functions of three variables, length, width and height, one of which can be expressed in terms of the other two. So one must optimize a function of two variables subject to a constraint, suggesting Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales I'm stuck with two variables in the equation for surface area once I made one of the sides equal 100/the other two sides and plugged that in.

Comment: @d.white You might gain some insight by solving the two dimensional problem first. What dimensions minimize the perimeter of a rectangle with fixed volume?

Comment: @EthanBolker okay thanks

Comment: Amending my earlier comment: Express both $S$ and $V$ as function of three variables and use the method of Lagrange multipliers with the constraint $LWH=100$. You should immediately find that $W=H=L$.

Comment: If the question has well-defined answer, then the optimum cannot be a rectangular prism (because we couldn't tell which one) ! So with closed eyes, the optimum is a cube and the answer is no (whatever the volume).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Volume:

$$ V=LWH=100 $$

Surface area:

$$ S=2LW+2LH+2WH $$

Using Lagrange multipliers:

$$ \nabla S=\lambda\nabla V $$

$$ \nabla S =(2W+2H,2L+2H,2L+2W) $$

$$ \nabla V=(WH,LH,LW) $$

\begin{eqnarray}
2W+2H&=&WH\lambda\\
2L+2H&=&LH\lambda\\
2L+2W&=&LW\lambda
\end{eqnarray}

Resulting in

\begin{eqnarray}
\lambda&=&\frac{2}{H}+\frac{2}{W}\\
&=&\frac{2}{H}+\frac{2}{L}\\
&=&\frac{2}{W}+\frac{2}{L}
\end{eqnarray}

So $L=W=H$. Therefore $LWH=100$ gives $L^3=100$, so $L=W=H=10^{2/3}$.

Comment: okay thank you so much! I still haven't done Lagrange multipliers but I will do some research, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $wlh=v$ and we can use this relation to eliminate $h$.

Then the (half) area is

$$wl+lh+hw=wl+\frac vw+\frac vl.$$

We minimize it by canceling the gradient,

$$\begin{cases}l-\dfrac v{w^2}=0,\\w-\dfrac v{l^2}=0\end{cases},$$ obviously giving $l=w=h$.